# How to one input type checkbox send value

Tags: php, html

```
<input class="bootstrap-switch switch-alt" type="checkbox" checked="false" data-on-color="success" data-off-color="default" name="check[]">
```

[image]

The default is `value = off`, but if the switch is open, the `value = NULL`.

I want it to be `value = no`.

Comment: remove the checked attribute at all

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to send only one checkbox value you don't need to create an array. Rename **name="check[]"** to **name='check'**. Also remove **checked="false"** attribute

You can simply use ternary operator to set it's value.

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $value = (!empty($_POST['check'])) ? 'on' : 'off';
        echo $value;
    }
```

Comment: Send multiple values, so need to use name="check[]".

Comment: Then you can simply loop through $_POST['check'] and set on/off value as mentioned above.